# Android: how to get the last 50 cell (tower) location details?

Tags: android, android-ndk

By default android stores the last 200 wifi connections and 50 cell location details.

I got the wifi details by using `getConfiguredNetworks()` from the `WifiManager`

Similarly I want to get the last 50 cell location details.

Please see https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.rrelmy.android.locationcachemap

In this example they passed the API key to the server. How do I get the key for my mobile?

Comment: +1 for a nice and interesting question.

Comment: What is your source for claiming that android stores the last 200 wifi connections and 50 cell locations?

Comment: @TomDignan http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-location-cache-viewer/com.bafflesoft.locationcache.viewer

Comment: @TomDignan https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/create-simple-cell-id-look-application-android

Comment: @TomDignan https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.rrelmy.android.locationcachemap
https://github.com/rrelmy/LocationCacheMap i know from all these sites tom

Answer (score 5):

According to this: https://github.com/rrelmy/LocationCacheMap accessing the cache you mentioned requires root and presumably because of that it isn't supported by the SDK.

What I did find, is that you can probably build your own location cache by listening for them: [follow these instructions](http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html) and store the lat,long pairs of the towers in a SQLite database.

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html is not opened>>>

Comment: i donot want to run the app in background @TomDignan

Comment: @venkat well i am no miracle worker. this is the best solution i can think of. if you try it please let me know if it works.